# Scipy convolution function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am looking into the python spicy convolve function at:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy.convolve

In the last example:

The two arrays are of the same length, so there is only one position where they completely overlap:

```
np.convolve([1,2,3],[0,1,0.5], 'valid')
array([ 2.5])
```

I am wondering why the result is `2.5`? Shouldn't it be:
`1*0 + 2*1 + 3*0.5 = 3.5` ?

Comment: Read the formula just below your own link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the convolution is the summation of the element-wise product but the first vector goes forward, and the second vector goes backwards.

It'll be:

```
1*0.5 + 2*1  + 1*0 = 2.5
```

Cheers.

Comment: I like this explanation. how can it be extended to the case of multivariate (more than 2) input distributions?